# Color Cell Based On Text Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, conditional-formatting

An Excel column contains a text value representing the category of that row.

Is there a way to format all cells having a distinct value a unique color without manually creating a conditional format for each value?

Example:  If I had the categories `bedroom, bedroom, bathroom, kitchen, living room`, I would want all cells containing `bedroom` to be a particular color, `bathroom` a different color, etc.

Comment: I would like it automatic if possible, similar to how colors are chosen for different series in a chart.

Comment: Ah, so you want all cell with the same contents to be the same color, but dont care which color it is?

Comment: Would a one-time macro (to create the conditional formats once) be acceptable? It would need to be run exactly **once** per workbook and could be removed after that.

Comment: soandos: Yes, TeX Hex: Sure!

Comment: A lot of people here might also be interested in this related question: "How to change background color of cell based on other cell value by VBA": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955832/how-to-change-background-color-of-cell-based-on-other-cell-value-by-vba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Copy the column you want to format to an empty worksheet.
2. Select the column, and then choose "Remove Duplicates" from the "Data Tools" panel on the "Data" tab of the ribbon.
3. To the right of your unique list of values or strings, make a unique list of numbers.  For instance, if you have 6 categories to color, the second column could just be 1-6.  This is your lookup table.
4. In a new column, use `VLOOKUP` to map the text string to the new color.
5. Apply conditional formatting based on the new numeric column.

Comment: But surely this then means the formatting is on the cells containing the numeric value and NOT the text value

Answer (score 13):

The screenshots below are from Excel 2010, but should be the same for 2007.

Select the cell and go to `Conditional Formatting | Highlight Cells Rules | Text that Contains`

To apply the conditional formatting for the entire worksheet select all cells then apply the Conditional Formatting.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Now Just select whatever formatting you want.

[image]

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis - NO. You can select ALL cells then use the conditional formatting. All cells that met the condition will be formatted accordingly.

Comment: Each condition still has to be created manually, even though they only need to be created a single time for the entire workbook. He's looking for a solution that doesn't require him to specify the values.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/861678-highlighting-rows-random-colors-if-there-duplicates-one-column.html#post4185738

```
Sub ColourDuplicates()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cel As Range
Dim Cel2 As Range
Dim Colour As Long




Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
Colour = 6
For Each Cel In Rng


If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, Cel) > 1 And Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
Set Cel2 = Rng.Find(Cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not Cel2 Is Nothing Then
        Firstaddress = Cel2.Address
        Do
        Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = Colour
        Cel2.Interior.ColorIndex = Colour
            Set Cel2 = Rng.FindNext(Cel2)

        Loop While Firstaddress <> Cel2.Address
    End If




Colour = Colour + 1


End If
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The automatic color choosing Conditional Formatting is not a feature of Microsoft Excel.

However, you can color an entire row based on the value of a category column individually.

1. Create a New Formatting Rule in Conditional Formatting.
2. Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
3. Formula: `=$B1="bedroom"` (Assuming the category column is B)
4. Set Format (using Fill color)
5. Apply rule formatting to all cells